# passing the imageView to the next activity, does it require an outlet

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I have minor problem that whenever I delete the Outlet (imageChosen) shown in the picture below (with the yellow warning), the app crashes when the image supposed to be passed
[image]

here how i defined it

```
 var imageChosen: UIImageView!
```

this is how i saved the image chosen from the gallery to the imageChosen

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        imageChosen.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        imageChosen.image = chosenImage
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)

    }
```

this where I pass the image to the next activity

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "next" {
            var pass:postView = segue.destinationViewController as! postView
            pass.currentImage = imageChosen.image
        }
    }
```

when I delete the outlet in the picture, the app crashes because the image is nil, even though the code seems to be okay,
can anyone please help me

Comment: Make it as normal property. Delete the outlet.

Comment: @AryamSaleh you need to delete connection of image view. Then try and inform me its working or not.

Comment: @Amit89 when i delete the outlet it crashes

Comment: @AshokLondhe i tried to delete the connection from storyboard, the app crashes, the reason is the imageChosen becomes nil

Comment: @AryamSaleh your not setting proper image to imageView. please set image properly and correct.

Comment: @AshokLondhe can you please check my code above, can you point to me what am i doing wrong please O_o

Comment: @AryamSaleh you are doing wrong...     var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage        Check if you have info named dictionary or not. your image is nil.

Comment: What does the warning in xcode say?

Comment: @IcaroNZ fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you keep getting the error is because you are assign image without allocation of your imageChosen.

**The Solution**

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        picker.delegate = self
        // Add this line
        imageChosen = UIImageView()

    }
```

After you have declare that **imageChosen = UIImageView()**, it will solve your problem

Hope that helps!

Comment: the yellow triangle in the picture still exist after i implement ur solution

Comment: Delete the yellow triangle on the storyboard

Answer (score 0):

You need to delete the outlet from the `ViewController`(swift file) as well, where you see the outlets in the pic you post click in the (x) to delete the outlet from imageChosen as it does not exist anymore (you can see the warning from Code in form of a yellow triangle).

You should also change your code to:

```
var imageChosen: UIImageView?
```

this is how i saved the image chosen from the gallery to the imageChosen

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as UIImage{
            imageChosen.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
            imageChosen.image = image
        }
        else
        {
            //something went wrong
        }
        dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("next", sender: self)

    }
```

this where I pass the image to the next activity

```
 override func prepareForSegue(segue: (UIStoryboardSegue!), sender: AnyObject!) {
        if segue.identifier == "next" {
            if let pass = segue.destinationViewController as postView
            {
                if let image = imageChosen.image{
                    pass.currentImage = imageChosen.image
                }
             }
        }
    }
```

I did it very verbose to make it easier to understand

Comment: when i delete it from the storyboard, the app crashes

Comment: Can you copy and past the error message that xcode display?

Comment: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value